# Difference between speech act and conversation act?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics

Since language has diversified uses, the course I am taking right now has diversified them into Linguistic act, Speech act, and Conversational act. The linguistic act is the utterance of a series of words in a meaningful order, which is sort of syntax oriented. And, then I got confused between the Speech act and Conversational Act, which I think are the same things.

Comment: This is local jargon, and we can't comment on its meaning or usage. Ask your professor.

Comment: You should probably give us some sort of definition of all three terms. Maybe you have reference books? Other than that, the question is about the specific terminology of a course, so it's probably best posed to the course's teacher.